# Updating Metadata in Anypoint Studio

Tags: dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule4

Is there any easy way to update the metadata within a project? I've been adding metadata so that I can define what is in the payload to make the intellisense work properly and use the 'preview' in my transform nodes. My metadata files are primarily .json files.

I have yet to find a 'good' way to update the metadata though. If I want to add a field to the json object I haven't found a good way to update it. I either have to:

1. Remove the metadata object, re-add it with the new field, and then re-attach the metadata to all the places it's used.
2. Edit the example files and the 'application-types' file

Comment: Your two ways are only ways I know. Except rewriting app from scratch ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

- Right click on your project and then select Mule > Manage Metadata types.
- Select the Metadata type you want to refresh, press the [...] then select the example actually present in your Anypoint Studio project folder (otherwise it will create another copy of the example file).
- At this point the application-types is automatically refreshed as well as Dataweave references.

Comment: Ok that's the missing piece. I figured out how to update the metadata but it was creating extra copies in the project folder.

So the process would be:
1. Update the metadata file in the project
2. Execute the steps you listed above

Comment: Confirmed this is working as explained. Thanks for the help!